# Removing characters/whitespace up to the first chosen character python

Tags: python

Here is a string:

```
.      68.00     68.00          .
```

I am trying to remove the first . and the fourth. while adding a comma between.

output should look like:

```
68.00,68.00
```

Have tried strip and some initial character removal functions but having issues e.g.
`[1:]`
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if there be more than just two numbers in the input?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this with [`re.findall()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp):

```
import re

st='.      68.00     68.00          .  '
print(','.join(re.findall('(?<!\d)(\d{2}.00)(?!\d)',st)))
```

Output:

```
68.00,68.00
```

If you have more numbers with different lengths and you only want those with length two, you could try this:

```
import re

st='.      68      67     .     600 '
print(','.join(re.findall('(?<!\d)(\d{2})(?!\d)',st)))   #you can change \d{2}, to \d{n} with n as the length you want
```

See the explanation of the regular expression [here](https://regexr.com/57iob).

Output:

```
68,68
```

**Edit:**
Another option without using regex:

```
st='.      68       68     .'
ls=[s for s in st.split() if all(let.isdigit() for let in s)]
print(','.join(ls))
```

Output:

```
68,68
```

Comment: I made a slight change to the question would this still work?

Comment: See the last edit @Kingswoop!! It will work with that...

Answer (score 1):

[Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) works for this problem. Here, instead of *removing the whitespace*, I'm *grabbing the numbers*, which is equivalent in your example. And then joining them with `','.join()`, of course.

```
>>> import re
>>> inp = '.      68       68          .                                       ' 
>>> print(','.join(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', inp)))
'68,68'
```

Comment: I have slightly altered the question would this still work?

Comment: To include the decimal point, you would want to change the search string accordingly. Say, to `r'[0-9.]+'`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using regex, the result could also be achieved by the combination of replace, split and join functions:

```
x = '.      68       68          .'
result = ','.join(x.replace('.','').split())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple (yet convoluted looking) regex search and replace. You may have to adjust this regex to your needs.

```
import re

the_input = '.      68.00       68.00          .     '
print(the_input)

# r = raw string
# the_regex = r'\s*\.\s*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+\.\s+'
the_regex = r'\s*\.\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+\.\s+' # with decimals numbers
the_output = re.sub(the_regex, r'\1,\2', the_input)
print(the_output)
```

the_regex is a bit convoluted so here is it broken down.

- \s* - spaces, 0 or more
- \. - one dot
- (\d+) - 1st pair of parenthesis means capture group 1. 2nd pair is 2nd group.
- \d+ - number digits, 1 or more
- \s+ - spaces, 1 or more

In re.sub(), \1 is capture group 1. \2 is capture group 2.

To test your regex and to have an explanation generated, punch your regex and input-string here:

https://regex101.com/

I suggest you use regex101 to truly understand this regex. Type out the input and then slowly type out the regex. Anything that matches the regex is highlighted and color coded.

Comment: i have slightly altered the question would this still work?

Comment: I changed my answer. I edited it and tested it. It's good.